# Remove-AppxPackage for all users

Tags: powershell, sysprep

I would like to remove the `Fitbit` package from the Microsoft Store apps in Window 10.
I have `-allusers` in the Powershell command but it's telling me Fitbit isn't in the current user.

I don't care what user it's in. I would like to find out why it won't remove it from all users.
I'm running this as `Administrator` with a user that has Administrator rights.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AppxPackage -allusers *fitbit* | Remove-AppxPackage                                         Remove-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF1, Package was not found.
Windows cannot remove Fitbit.FitbitCoach_4.4.133.0_x64__6mqt6hf9g46tw because the current user does not have that
package installed. Use Get-AppxPackage to see the list of packages installed.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 8a315047-822f-0000-d65f-318a2f82d501 in the Event Log or use
the command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID 8a315047-822f-0000-d65f-318a2f82d501
At line:1 char:38
+ Get-AppxPackage -allusers *fitbit* | Remove-AppxPackage
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Fitbit.FitbitCo...__6mqt6hf9g46tw:String) [Remove-AppxPackage], PSInval
   idOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.RemoveAppxPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify -AllUsers with Remove-AppxPackage.  You also need to be in **Windows 10 1809 or above** for it to work.  Below that version, "remove-appxpackage -allusers" may run without error and still not work.  Confusingly, the allusers parameter to get-appxpackage has *no effect* on remove-appxpackage.  This will only affect profiles that already exist.  "Remove-AppxPackage -User" has never worked.

```
 Get-AppxPackage -allusers fitbit* | Remove-AppxPackage -allusers
```

Or

```
Remove-AppxPackage Fitbit.FitbitCoach_4.4.133.0_x64__6mqt6hf9g46tw -AllUsers
```

Comment: Thank you,  I ran it.  I didn't get an error so I assume it ran.  When I run sysprep I get an error saying: SYSPRP Package Fitbit.FitbitCoach_4.4.133.0_x64__6mqt6hf9g46tw was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not function properly in the sysprep image.

Comment: Sounds like it didn't work.  Is it windows 10 1809 or above?  You might have to login as that user and remove it.

Comment: I have two users plus Administrator.  I have logged in under all three and ran:

Comment: I have two users plus Administrator.  I have logged in under all three and ran: Get-AppxPackage -allusers *Fitbit.FitbitCoach* | Remove-AppxPackage -allusers  and I also ran: Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | where Displayname -EQ "Fitbit.FitbitCoach" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online   to remove the provision.  Running in Windows 10 1903. I'm still getting the same error: SYSPRP Package Fitbit.FitbitCoach_4.4.133.0_x64__6mqt6hf9g46tw was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not function properly in the sysprep image.

Comment: It usually says in the PackageUserInformation property who has it installed.

Comment: Sorry to dig this off, but that can help someone maybe : For me, `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *Feedback*  | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers` gives me an unauthorized error but `Get-AppxPackage -AllUser *Feedback*  | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUser` works fine. App is removed. Notice the difference between `-AllUsers`/`-AllUser`

Comment: @vinalti It's just a unique abbreviation of the same parameter.

Comment: Yeah, so I noticed that actually when run the first time i have an error, and when run a second time I have no error anymore. I published a script to uninstall preinstalled applications from Windows devices. [Fint it on Github, here](https://github.com/Vinalti/Windows-Remove-Preinstalled-Apps) Recently made a PR for removing packages to `-AllUsers`